# hibernate returns more rows than expected

Tags: hibernate

I have my query that returns 662 rows when it is run using sql explorer and when i run it in code using hibernate it returns 856 rows...I tried using a set and getting rid of the duplicates that way but apparently there aren't any duplicates...

***Query:***

```
String queryString = "FROM AEntity AS A " +
                     "LEFT JOIN A.bEntityAS B " +
                     "WHERE A.INIT||A.NUM IN (:carList) AND A.INIT IN (:initList) AND A.NUM IN (:numberList) " + 
                     "AND B.TRUK_AXL_CNT > 0";
```

***Classes***

```
public class BEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NUM")
    private String num;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INIT")
    private String init;

    @Column(name = "V_CNT")
    private Integer vcnt;
}

public class AEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NUM")
    private String num;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INIT")
    private String init;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="NUM", referencedColumnName="NUM"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="INIT", referencedColumnName="INIT")
    })
    private BEntity bEntity;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `EAGER` fetching?  It would help if we could see your mappings.

Comment: im using annotations i'll add my classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the other answers worked - but it was determined that for whatever reason hibernate returned the correct results while sql explorer was returning incorrect results. All of the two character initials in the result set were eliminated by sql explorer...giving false results.

Hibernate was correct!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `Criteria`, try something like:

`criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`

Otherwise, try using the `DISTINCT` keyword in your HQL.

`select distinct a from AEntity a...`

The issue is explained a bit at the top of [this](http://blog.xebia.com/2008/12/11/sorting-and-pagination-with-hibernate-criteria-how-it-can-go-wrong-with-joins/) article.

Comment: it still returns the 856 results using criteria... and it blows up saying invalid keyword near select distinct when i use DISTINCT

Comment: actually i take that back about criteria...can you give me an example of how my query would be using criteria...

Comment: The [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) is pretty straight forward.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
WHERE A.INIT||A.NUM IN (:carList)
```

doesn't do what you expect to be done.

If you have one entity with

```
INIT = 1, NUM = 34
```

and another entity with

```
INIT = 13, NUM = 4
```

then in both cases the expression `A.INIT||A.NUM` evaluates to `134`, and if you look for the entity with `INIT = 1, NUM = 34` only, then your select nevertheless fetches both entities.

To make this working you have to use a separator character which does not appear in any possible INIT or NUM value. Let's use in this example '+' as the separator character, then change your select to

```
WHERE A.INIT || '+' || A.NUM IN (:carList)
```

and your values in the carlist must be prepared with the same separator character.

Comment: init stands for initial so the initial is an completely alpha string and num is numeric string...so it would be AAAA 0000000000 is how it looks...and in that carlist there are things that look like AAAA0000000000

Comment: OK, if INIT never has a number and NUM always is purely numeric, then it works. But that I couldn't see from your codelet :-\ and it could have been the source of your problem.